# How to set a variable inside do block in postgres (sql file)

Tags: postgresql, psql

This is the oracle sql code

```
    variable retval number
    set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off
    DECLARE
    retval numeric;
    p_ret numeric(9) ;

    BEGIN
    begin

     test();
            p_ret := 0;

            EXCEPTION
                    WHEN OTHERS THEN
                            p_ret := sqlcode ;
    end ;

    :retval := ( p_ret  ) ;
 END ;
 /
exit  :retval;
/
```

Variable retval is being set inside the block.
What is the equivalent in postgresql?

Comment: That code would only work in `sqlplus` - are you looking for a `psql` equivalent?

Comment: Yes i am looking for a psql equivalent